# Docker: Permissions error on OpenShift Origin 3.6

Tags: docker, openshift

I'm trying to run a pretty simple Flask API in OpenShift Origin 3.6. I can build this container just fine locally and remotely, but when I go to deploy on OpenShift, I get permissions errors on the `RUN chmod -R 777 ...` lines. Has anyone found a way around this? I wonder if my corporate environment doesn't allow this type of copying, but it's all within a container...

Edit: providing a completely minimal example

Directory structure:

```
project
├── Dockerfile
└── app
    └── api.py
```

`Dockerfile` to build base image:

```
FROM docker.io/ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    cmake curl git make gunicorn nginx python3 python3-pip python3-setuptools build-essential \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install pandas numpy scikit-learn scipy xgboost flask-restful nltk gunicorn

RUN mkdir -p /home/app

WORKDIR /
RUN python3 -c 'import nltk; nltk.download("punkt")'
RUN mv /root/nltk_data /home/app
```

I then run `docker build . -t project:latest --no-cache`. Next, the `Dockerfile` that uses the base image from above to deploy the actual application (I basically just comment out the "base image" lines from above and uncomment these ones from below, using the same `Dockerfile` file):

```
FROM project:latest

COPY app /home/app

RUN chmod -R 777 /home/app

WORKDIR /home/app

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python3", "api.py"]
```

I build the container to be deployed using `docker build . -t project:app --no-cache`.

`api.py`:

```
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        print('This app is running')
        time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: have you got root?

Comment: I'm not sure. How could I verify that within Openshift or the container itself? I know another guy runs containers on OSO without root, but I've also heard from others that you need non-root to run apps.

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of the actual error logs from the build? Confirm that you are talking about having used a docker build in OpenShift. The non-root issue relates to runtime, not build time.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, `Step 3/11 : RUN chmod -R 777 /home/app
 ---> Running in b2cca0339697

chmod: changing permissions of '/home/app': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/home/app': Operation not permitted
Removing intermediate container b2cca0339697
error: build error: The command '/bin/sh -c chmod -R 777 /home/app' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Comment: You are hitting an obscure bug in Docker which can occur when using certain layered file systems with Docker. It arises because you are trying to give a directory created in a previous layer more open permissions than it was created with in the previous layer.

Comment: Although handling permissions in the way you are is not really the best way of doing things, add ``RUN chmod -R 777 /home/app`` after where you originally created the directory in the base image and you should be okay.

Comment: BTW, why not use the OpenShift Python S2I builder rather than creating an image yourself from scratch?

Comment: Whoops, you actually want ``RUN mkdir -p /home/app && chmod 0777 /home/app``. You still need the later chmod as well after populating ``/home/app``.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, thank you! I basically tore everything down, pushing a brand-new image to Docker Hub, new application on OpenShift, and am going to specify `noCache: true` in the build strategy going forward.